# I am getting a corrupted variable error

Tags: c

Well I have a lab to do for homework and I was wondering if someone could help me out with this. The program keeps saying that my variable is corrupted. If anyone can help me out that would be great. Btw don't mind the questions lol.

```
int main (void)
{
char answer;

printf("welcome to the celebrity look alike game. You will be asked 5 yes or no questions. To answer please either put a y for yes or an n for no");
printf("\nQuestion 1: Do you have brown eyes?");
scanf("%1s", &answer);
if (answer=='y')
    {printf("\nQuestion 2:Do you have white hair?");
    scanf("%1s", &answer);
    if (answer=='y')
        printf("\nQuestion 3:Is your height around 5 feet 10 inches?");
        scanf("%1s", &answer);
        if (answer=='y')
            printf("\nQuestion 4:Are you a slim man?");
            scanf("%1s", &answer);
            if (answer=='y')
                printf("\nQuestion 5: Do you dress well?");
                scanf("%1s", &answer);
                if (answer=='y');
                    printf("You really look like Matt Leblanc!");}
else printf("Sorry, you do not look like this celebrity.");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. First, you need to edit to add appropriate language tags, so it's clear what you're asking about and the people knowledgeable about that language can see it easily. (Add the `C` tag.) Second, you've given no useful information. What line of the code is causing the problem? (The debugger should help you find it.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `answer` is of datatype `char`, but `scanf()` is told to treat it as a character array with a length of (at least) 2.  This causes `scanf()` to write past the variable into whatever happens to lay in memory.  In this case, there is not another variable to scribble on, and it probably is corrupting the program's stack.

There are several ways to fix that problem.

There are several other problems with the code:

- The if..then..else structure is flawed.  It will not show the "do not look like this celebrity" message unless all the conditions *except* the last one are true.
- Indentation does not determine statement nesting.  You have to explicitly use curly braces to group statements.
- For predictably dealing with user input, you might want to insist they answer with `y` or `n`.  As the program is written, it will accept `X` and `7` as synonyms for "no".

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `scanf("%1s", &answer);` to `scanf("%c", &answer);`. The former will try to read a *string*, and this requires two characters - the one read and the null character to terminate the *string*. The latter just reads a character.

As `answer` is only one character the reading of a *string* will corrupt your memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are using `scanf` as follows:

```
scanf("%1s", &answer);
```

While your variable `answer` is just a single `char`.  Remember that C strings are always terminated with a null character, so a string with just one character in it will require storage for two characters - the character itself and the null terminator.  Consequently, when you try to store that string in a single character, you end up trashing memory right after your `char` variable, since `scanf` is trying to put a null character there.

To fix this, either change your declaration of `answer` to be `char answer[2]`, or change your `scanf` so that you read a single character:

```
scanf("%c", &answer);
```

Or alternatively use `getchar()`.

Hope this helps!